# Eureka and Feign client prevent springboot from shutting down

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, feign

I just want to develop an application based on spring-boot. What I expected is the application will do some tasks and then exit.
It needs to call remote rest API for some data. So I used Feign.
What I encountered now is the application can not stop automatically. I called `DiscoveryManager.getInstance().shutdownComponent();` , but other services are still there getting the application stuck.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

        DiscoveryManager.getInstance().shutdownComponent();

    }
}

    @Component
    @FeignClient(value = "DATA-MGT")
    interface RemoteService {
        @GetMapping(value = "/info/{code}")
        String getConfig(@PathVariable String code);
    }
```

Does anybody has some experiences on this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What Spring dependencies are you using? Some dependencies like spring-boot-starter-web keep the main thread running indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, I was able to fix it just adding the code below where I want it to stop the execution. I guess thay maybe it's not the correct way to fix it, but it works.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Edit 1: I noticed that after a few minutes, Java closes normally.
Edit 2: I tend to believe that you are looking for running the application as batch, am I right ? Thus, I found on Spring documentation a post about this, take a look.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Summing up, to stop the execution of your application, use the code model below.

```
package com.example.batchprocessing;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchProcessingApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(BatchProcessingApplication.class, args)));
  }
}
```